# How do I set link color in Nativescript HtmlView tag?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I need to change a link color in the HtmlView on iOS. On Android I can set the default color by editing `/app/App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/values/colors.xml`. I cannot find a way how to do that on iOS. Any help will be really appreciated.

I have tried using inline styles {N} properties but nothing seems to effect the color of a link. It works for paragraph tag or span but it just does not effect links.

**simplified/explaining code**

```
    <HtmlView html="
        <span>just some text </span>
        <br>
        <p style='text-align: center;'>
            <span style='color: red;'>this will get colored </span>
            <br>
            <a href='https://google.com'>link - this will not get colored</a>
        </p>
    "></HtmlView>
```

**Images how it looks on the devices:**

[image: ios]

[image: android]

I can't add it as image here...it wants 10+ reputation which I don't have.

Thank you in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: In the image the color is already highlighted in red, so are you saying you want to set a default color for rest of the text in HTML?

Comment: @Manoj I need the links to be colored. As I mentioned before everything but links (the A tag) works. __I probably should of mention__ that what I need on iOS is so that the blue is green as on the android version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may adjust the **tintColor** (iOS) / **textColorLink** (Android) on the native object.

**HTML**

```
     <HtmlView @loaded="onLoaded" html="
        <span>just some text </span>
        <br>
        <p style='text-align: center;'>
            <span style='color: red;'>this will get colored </span>
            <br>
            <a href='https://google.com'>link - this will not get colored</a>
        </p>
    "></HtmlView>
```

**Methods**

```
import * as colorModule from "tns-core-modules/color";

onLoaded: function(args) {
   const color = new colorModule.Color("green");
   if (args.object.ios) {
      args.object.ios.tintColor = color.ios;
   } else {
      args.object.android.setLinkTextColor(color.android);
   }
}
```

Comment: I will try it and let you know. Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: Thank you!! It works!! I really appreciate your help.